# Circular permutations - $n$ sitting at a round table without repeating neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I hope this isn't a duplicate - the problem is to find the number of ways of sitting $n$ people (who initially were sitting in the order $1, 2, \dots,n$, with $1$ and $n$ being neighbors) at a round table so that no two people that were neighbors initially are neighbors again. 
I understand that if there were no restrictions there were $(n-1)!$ different ways to arrange them. 
If the place of a person matters, for $n \leq 4$ I don't get any solution, for $n = 5$ I get $10$ ways, for $n = 6$, $84$ ways, for $n = 7$, $630$ ways and for $n = 8$ I get $5168$ solutions using an algorithm based on a adjacency matrix. Making that algorithm was easy comparing to finding a relation between n and the results I got (which are hopefully correct).

My way of thinking was to subtract from $(n-1)!$ a number equal to the bad combinations as reflected here [arrangement of NOT sitting together](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489262/arrangement-of-not-sitting-together) but I get a negative number even for $n = 5$, for which I know I already have $10$ solutions. 
If the place doesn't matter and $13524$ and $14253$ are considered equivalent, then for $n = 5$ I only get one solution. 
It's been a long time since I studied combinatorics and I don't seem to find the right way to wrap my mind around this, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are $1,n$ considered neighbors, originally?

Comment: Yes, 1 and n are considered neighbors.

Comment: Are rotations of an arrangement considered to be equivalent?

Comment: Not necesarily, 13524 and 14253 may be considered different.

Comment: @0ana : 13524 and 14253 are not related by a rotation but by a reversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence you wanted to compute is [A089222](https://oeis.org/A089222), which starts n=5 : 10, 36, 322, ...
but the more fundamental one is [A078603](https://oeis.org/A078603), where you confound 2 arrangements if they differ only by a rotation of the table, and starts n=5 : 2, 6, 46, 354, ... and then there is [A002816](https://oeis.org/A002816) where the orientation (clockwise/counterclockwise) does not count either : 1, 3, 23, 177, ... .

If you follow the links I give to the Encyclopedia of integer sequences, you will find a few references, articles and formulas (notably one of the binomial inclusion/exclusion type) about this problem and a few of its interpretations.

The question is little more involved that it seems.

I believe two problems you had when you tried to find all cases for n>=5 is that you were starting with one fixed point ( $(n-1)!$ possibilities) ) and that you subtracted impossibilities based on $n!$ configurations. Also in your implementation of a computer algorithm, you may have not exhausted all the conditions/positions to exclude, and you would have been better off looking only for the configurations starting with 1 (i.e. up to rotation).

For reference, for n=6 the 6 arrangements starting with 1 are

> {1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4},
> {1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 5},
>
> {1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 5},
> {1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3},
>
> {1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3},
> {1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 4}